# How to check if powershell is running under VS Developer Command Prompt

Tags: powershell

I have a script that issues some tf git commands. I want to ensure the powershell host was started from the VS developer command prompt so it has access to tf.exe. I thought I could try to run a tf command and check the exit code:

```
invoke-command -ScriptBlock {tf git /?} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$isRunningDevCmd = $LASTEXITCODE
if ($isRunningDevCmd -ne 0) {
    write-host "You must run this script under a developer command prompt for access to tf.exe. Commands will be printed below for you to run manually."
    exit
}
```

It did not suppress the error and the $LASTEXITCODE was null when I did not run under a dev cmd prompt.

Comment: @iRon I tried this, but did not yield a difference between VS command prompt and standard cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by checking for an exception instead.

```
$isRunningDevCmd = 1
try{
    invoke-command -ScriptBlock {tf git /?} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
catch{
    $isRunningDevCmd = 0
} 
if ($isRunningDevCmd -eq 0) {
    write-host "You must run this script under a developer command prompt for access to tf.exe. Commands will be printed below for you to run manually."    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check if the tf command is available:

```
$isRunningDevCmd = !!(Get-Command 'tf' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
```